# UI builder raycasting prevention doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[How the UI looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/envwg.png)

I can only click on the top most button and on the "Earth" text. But anything below that and the UI dissapears, due to this code:

```
private void SelectPlane(RaycastHit hit)
    {
        //Makes it so when you click UI elements there will be no selection
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
        {
            selectedAstronomicalObject = null;
            //uiManager.showPlanet(selectedAstronomicalObject);
            ui.hidePlanetUI();
        }
    }
```

But the fix

```
!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()
```

That works on normal unity UI does not work anymore. Thanks for the help.

Edit:
I have found out that zooming in and out with the camera changes how many buttons I can click. Maybe the camera position has something to do with it?

Comment: Have you toggle `Raycast Target` on for all the ui elements?

Comment: I don't know where to find or how to do that on the new UI builder.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Basically, the main camera needs to always be at inside the canvas, so I simply moved my game objects to other coordinates. This is probably a bit of a clutch fix but it works.